# add a foreach action in an output return

Tags: foreach, slider

Hello i want to make a dynamic slider with bootstrap but my pics is not in the slider. Each one is showing line by line. How can i add the $output with foreach function's PHP ? Thank you for your help.

```
function make_slides( $connexion ) {
global $data_projet;

$dir = '../../00_sources/img/upload/' . $data_projet . '/mockups/';
$images = glob( $dir . "*" );
foreach ( $images as $image );

$output = '';
$count = 0;
$result = make_query( $connexion );
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    $data_projet = $row[ 'projet_nom' ];
    if ( $count == 0 ) {
        $output .= '<div class="carousel-item active">';
    } else {
        $output .= '<div class="carousel-item">';
    }

    foreach ( $images as $image ){
                    echo    '<img class="d-block w-100" src="'.$image.'" alt="' . $image . '" />';
                } 

    $output .='</div>
';
    $count = $count + 1;
}
return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i've tried something else and it works now.